# contactsd using over 50% CPU on my MacBook Air

Tags: macos, performance, cpu, sonoma

I wanted to get some information with regards to the `contactsd` process on my MacBook Air. I often find it using over 50% of my CPU and I would like to know about it and how to disable its excessive usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all networks and then restart your Mac to see that this process needs to respond to so,e contact changes and then should be quiet.

Watch it as you rejoin a network. If it chews cpu endlessly, you may need to troubleshoot the data sources for your contacts. Especially ones that sync over a network.